# Assert failed - Training Tesseract

Tags: windows, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to train tesseract with Serak Tesseract Trainer:https://code.google.com/p/serak-tesseract-trainer/ and I can't figure out why the following error in the CMD is happening while executing Train Tesseract. Any help?

```
Reading a.tr ...
Font id = -1/0, class id = 1/46 on sample 0
font_id >= 0 && font_id < font_id_map_.SparseSize():Error:Assert failed:in file
..\classify\trainingsampleset.cpp, line 622
```

Comment: Do you have a valid font_properties file or correct input filename? http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/issues/detail?id=867

Comment: @nguyenq Ok founded. The problem was on the input filename which should be something like this: ell.arial.exp0.tiff . Thanks a lot my friend!

Comment: @nguyenq I have post another question about merge two traineddata files. If you know anything: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931643/merge-trained-data-files-tesseract , Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Before writing your font data put '\n' char beginig of the file(just hit enter).
Worked for me.

Comment: This indeed solves the problem - the program passes. But also prints a warning: "Failed to load unicharset from file unicharset" and generates a useless output file. The effect is the same as if you just removed the unicharset file. In my case it was a problem with file names. See Devabc's anwer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28930343/1785520