# Merge trained data files - Tesseract

Tags: file, merge, ocr, tesseract

I'm using two traineddata files in tesseract in order to recognize two languages. But because the accuracy wasn't good enough, I trained tesseract and produce a new traineddata file which I want to merge it with one of the two language files I use. So my question is: How can it be possible to merge the new traineddata file with one of the files that is found here: https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list .Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can [unpack](http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/combine_tessdata.1.html) the existing `.traineddata` and merge the components separately; however, I'm not sure that's going to work. You can create your `ell1.traineddata` and specify it together with the existing one at the command line, such as:

```
tesseract image output -l ell+ell1
```

Comment: I'll try to unpack .traineddata and merge the components seperatly because I want to use in this case three languages which are eng+ell+ell1. I'll try and tell you! Thanks!