# Train tesseract stopped working

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I'm using Serak Tesseract Trainer for Tesseract 3.0x. I added a Train Image, which then came from jTessBoxEditor (a Box Generator). When I pressed Train Tesseract, a DOS command prompts me, it's like training the image, then suddenly this appeared:

**Reading dos.bookmanoldstyle.exp0.tr ... Font id = -1/0, class id =       1/42 on sample 0 font_id >= 0 && font_id <       font_id_map_.SparseSize():Error:Assert failed:in file       ....\classify\trainingsampleset.cpp, line 622**

then a dialog box appeared that tells something about Shape clustering that has stopped working.

I don't know what went wrong, the first time I used this, it worked fine though. Anyone who can help me resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Save your `font_properties` file in Unix format (`.sh`) (which is available in notepad++) instead of normal text. Then use font_properties file as shown below wherever it is needed.

```
-F font_properties.sh
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony. Saving as Unix format worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a correct entry in font_properties file or correct input filename? [Assert failed - Training Tesseract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921810/assert-failed-training-tesseract)

Comment: Where can I locate the font_properties file? I think I had the correct input file "dos.arial.exp0.tiff".

Comment: It's described in [TrainingTesseract3](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3) page.