# Warning : no protos/config when trying to train Tesseract

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm trying to train tesseract, because it mainly confuses "g" with "9" when reading my .tiff files.

After deducing the font used in the .tiff files seemed to be "Pragmatica Book", I decided to follow [this tutorial](https://www.joyofdata.de/blog/a-guide-on-ocr-with-tesseract-3-03/) to train my tesseract on usual characters in Pragmatica font.

The snag is, when it comes to the command :

> shapeclustering -F font_properties -U unicharset eng2.LobsterTwo.exp0.tr

it gives :

> Bad properties for index n, char A: 0,255 0,255 0,0 0,0 0,0

with n going from 3 to 64,

and as many lines of

> Computing shape distances...
>
> Stopped with 0 merged, min dist 999.000000

This results in the next step by giving :

> Bad properties for index n, char l: 0,255 0,255 0,0 0,0 0,0

for n from 3 to 64, followed by

> Warning: no protos/configs for sh0058 in CreateIntTemplates()

I found [this former post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025965/mftraining-gives-warning-no-protos-configs-for-f-in-createinttemplates) dealing with that issue, but all the related answers raise the fact that font name is different in .tr file and in font_properties, which is not my case here, as both names are "Pragmatica".

Thanks in advance for your help, I don't see what I did wrong !

Comment: I have the same problem.  I am running tesseract 3.04.01 on Unbuntu 16.04 LTS, and I am following the same "joy of data" blog posting that you are.  I get all the errors, 64 lines listed as having "Bad properties", and the "Warning: no protos/configs" blah blah.  Strangely, however, when I use the final traineddata file with tesseract, it works reading the new font brilliantly.  Have you found out any more?